# HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I need you help me for this error in my code

```
form

<form:form action="user.do" method="POST" commandName="user">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <form:input path="userName" cssClass="form-control "/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <form:password path="password" cssClass="form-control "/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Login" class="btn btn-info col-xs-12"/>
                    </div>

                    </form:form>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String doAction(@ModelAttribute Users user,Model model, BindingResult result,Map<String, Object> map)
{
    Users user1 = new Users();
    user1 = userService.userLogin(user);
    user1 = userService!=null ? user1 : new Users();

    map.put("user", userService.userLogin(user));
    return "home";
}
```

Implementation  Dao Clsss

```
    package com.hmy.Dao.Impl;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.hmy.Dao.UsersDao;
import com.hmy.Model.Users;

@Repository
public class UsersDaoImpl implements UsersDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory session;

    @Override
    public Users userLogin(Users user) {

        return (Users)session.getCurrentSession().get(Users.class, user.getUserName());
    }

}


[Implementation of Service class][1]
```

Error display when try to submit data

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException:
>   Failed to invoke handler method [public java.lang.String
>   com.hmy.Controller.UsersController.doAction(com.hmy.Model.Users,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,java.util.Map)];
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Errors/BindingResult argument declared without preceding model
>   attribute. Check your handler method signature!
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException:
>   Failed to invoke handler method [public java.lang.String
>   com.hmy.Controller.UsersController.doAction(com.hmy.Model.Users,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,java.util.Map)];
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Errors/BindingResult argument declared without preceding model
>   attribute. Check your handler method signature!
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException:
>   Failed to invoke handler method [public java.lang.String
>   com.hmy.Controller.UsersController.doAction(com.hmy.Model.Users,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,java.util.Map)];
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Errors/BindingResult argument declared without preceding model
>   attribute. Check your handler method signature!
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   root cause
>
> org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException:
>   Failed to invoke handler method [public java.lang.String
>   com.hmy.Controller.UsersController.doAction(com.hmy.Model.Users,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,java.util.Map)];
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Errors/BindingResult argument declared without preceding model
>   attribute. Check your handler method signature!
>     org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:181)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   root cause
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Errors/BindingResult argument
>   declared without preceding model attribute. Check your handler method
>   signature!
>     org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:327)
>     org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/8.0.28 logs.

So i need your help to solve this, Because it my fisrt time to try Spring with hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your current Spring Version.

But check if you need to place `BindingResult`right after `@ModelAttribute` within the method signature

Since you're not performing any validation from what I see, you can remove `BindingResult`entirely from the method signature.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/errorsbindingresult-argument-declared-without-preceding-model-attribute/

Comment: Np mate.. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

hello if you want to know how to combine Spring and hibernate i made a source code or i mean template this is the line https://github.com/Try-Parser/FDFBaseCodeJava it is a Spring MVC with Spring security you can explore there i made it more simpler than other if it helps you thank you haha and by the way i didnt see your spring-servlet.xml that also your hibernate configuration .xml file

Comment: in case of spring-servlet.xml and hibernate configuration it Ok.

Comment: And I have no error for now and my project work correct